# CSS with Bullets (opacity and box issues)

Tags: html, css, opacity

My issue is with with the text of an unordered list.

I have a background image and want about 60% opacity on a white box around both the bullets and the text. I originally put it outside an `<li>` and it seems the validator doesn't like that.

Another problem is the text is under the 60% opacity so the colors all don't really pop. They are washed out because of the opacity.

**HTML :**

```
<ul>
    <li><div class="faded slim">&nbsp;</div></li>
    <li><div class="faded"><a href="snowplowing.html">Snow Removal</a></div></li>
    <li><div class="faded"><a href="landscape.html">Landscape Construction</a></div></li>
    <li><div class="faded"><a href="parking.html">Parking Lot Maintenance</a></div></li>
    <li><div class="faded slim">&nbsp;</div></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS :**

```
.faded {
    opacity: 0.4;
    height: 19px;
    width: 175px;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.slim {
    height: 13px;
}
```

Comment: I guess I neglected to say I want a space between every li element hence why I didn't put it around the entire ul like everyone is suggesting. I want just the bullet and the text. Not the entire ul.

Comment: The CSS may work but the html still doesn't apply the styles in the way mentioned. How can I style both the bullet and the text and leave a space in between the li's? Either I style the whole list (ul) or inside the li which leaves the bullet still not surrounded by the box.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tWRdM/21/

Comment: I was trying to remove the disc bullet from slim too and was running into some problems with removing it.

Comment: I just want the bullet point from the top slim and bottom slim gone AND i want the existing bullet points to be in a block of white with the background showing thru.

Comment: That's exactly it! I was hoping for IE7 support but I'm not sure the negative number and the selector you are using work. Firefox, Chrome, IE7+ if possible.

Comment: My Head Hurts, thanks for your solution. Is it possible in IE7+? IE9 works but IE7 and IE8 don't work correctly.

Comment: Closest I can get I am afraid: http://jsfiddle.net/JWE69/ - might be worth putting in an IE7 hack just to get rid of all the bullet points

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the background opacity to the ul not li

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/mjz2Z/) is the example

**HTML**

```
<div id="a">
    <ul class="faded">
        <li><div ><a href="snowplowing.html">Snow Removal</a></div></li>
        <li><div><a href="landscape.html">Landscape Construction</a></div></li>
        <li><div><a href="parking.html">Parking Lot Maintenance</a></div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.faded {
    width: 175px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    padding: 13px 0;
}
#a {
    background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
    padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: Please keep all relative code as part of your answer - external links my stop working and then your answer can no longer help the community

Answer (score 0):

- Give your `ul` the class `faded` instead of all the `li` elements.
- Use some padding on the `ul` so you can get rid of the `.slim` list items.
- And use an `rgba` background color instead of opacity.

Answer (score 0):

HI you can used two method first is you can give `li class` and define to properties `list-style: none;`

AS like this

**Css**

```
.buletnone{
list-style:none !important;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
                    <li class="buletnone"><div class="faded slim">&nbsp;</div></li>
                    <li><div class="faded"><a href="snowplowing.html">Snow Removal</a></div></li>
                    <li><div class="faded"><a href="landscape.html">Landscape Construction</a></div></li>
                    <li><div class="faded"><a href="parking.html">Parking Lot Maintenance</a></div></li>
                    <li class="buletnone"><div class="faded slim">&nbsp;</div></li>
                </ul>
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/tWRdM/30/

### -------------------------------------------

### -------------------------------

Second is define first and last child define in your css as like this

```
#mainTitle table tr td ul li:first-child, #mainTitle table tr td ul li:last-child{
list-style:none;
}
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/tWRdM/31/